# Making a Web API controller returning a IQueryable list asynchronous

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I've been trying to make the following controller method asynchronous

```
public IQueryable<Category> GetCategories()
{
    return _context.Categories;
}
```

I've added the following to make it asynchronous

```
public async Task<IQueryable<Category>> GetCategories()
{
    return await _context.Categories;
}
```

The type System.Data.Entity.DbSet is not awaitable

I'm not sure how to get the db context to return all the entities while maintaining the IQueryable.

How do you make the above method asynchronous? Thanks or the help.

Comment: I doubt you can do that, however async functionality is only available on EF6 onwards, are you using EF6?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you're implementing an OData endpoint. If you do it at this level (returning a `DbSet` directly from your controller), the asynchronous nature is entirely up to WebAPI; all you're doing is returning it an `IQueryable` that it can use synchronously or asynchronously.

There's nothing you can do to "make" it asynchronous, and there's no reason to.

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution I found:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Category>> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Category> options)
{
     var myQueryable = (IQueryable<Category>)options.ApplyTo(context.Categories);   
     return await myQueryable.ToListAsync();
}
```

It works async and applies the filter.

Comment: There is no reason to do this. IQueryable is not a request to your database. If you create a controller from the Asp.net template, you will notice that they do not put a async on the Get() call for that reason.

Comment: What I wanted is when IQueryable is executed the request to database is executed asynchronously so that less threads are used. So it is necessary in that sense. Without above technique, when the thread hits  to DB, the thread will stay alive idle till DB returns a response.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, and for some reason I cannot use `.ToListAsync()` directly, also VS didn't allow me to use the QueryableExtensions namespace. At the end, I decided to implement the whole code like:

```
var categories = await System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.ToListAsync(context.Categories.Where(c => c.Name != "On Sale"));
```