# In ASP.NET Core 6, is an IQueryable returned by a controller action enumerated asynchronously?

Tags: asp.net-core, iqueryable

My question is similar to [Making a Web API controller returning a IQueryable list asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20584400/making-a-web-api-controller-returning-a-iqueryable-list-asynchronous) from 2013, and related to [Should I call ToListAsync() when make a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59840099/should-i-call-tolistasync-when-make-a-query). I want to focus specifically on the claim by multiple users (including the highly regarded [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20585204/1953590)) that it is "not necessary" to explicitly enumerate an `IQueryable` asynchronously.

I know that in recent versions of ASP.NET Core, a controller can return an `IAsyncEnumerable` and it will be enumerated asynchronously. Is the answer simply that the framework does the same thing with `IQueryable`?

And to throw a wrench into what may otherwise be a simple answer, do the [potential problems with unbuffered streaming](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/32483#issuecomment-849348895) of an `IAsyncEnumerable` also apply to `IQueryable`?

Comment: Technically I think the SQL is doing the enumeration when it returns a dataset. So that part is beyond the .cs code. Maybe that's what Stephen he means when he says it's not necessary. A call to enumerate, such as .ToList() just causes EF to create and run the deferred query.  Still the rule of thumb is to keep async "all the way through", so it couldn't hurt to use ToListAsync() so you don't lock while waiting for the query to return it's results.

Comment: @pcalkins The old answers I found seem to say to use neither. But something eventually has to call one of those, so I'm trying to understand why it's okay or desirable to defer it in the controller. (Obviously it's useful to return `IQueryable` from a service if more queries might be applied in the controller.)

Comment: Eventually you'll need to return data to the client.  Unless the client is making the DB or context call?  But the ToAsyncList() call must always be awaited since the context will be tied up until the query is complete.  That might be another reason that ToList() is essentially the same.  (To keep my brain straight I always use async calls... but ToListAsync() might also have a tiny bit more overhead...)

Comment: maybe the part I'm missing is the conversion of dataset to POCO (model)... ToListAsync() maybe EF uses IEnumerableAsync interface when ToListAsync() is called?   I generally return a Task, or a List<> of a certain type, but I think EF is doing that conversion somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IQueryable` doesn't extend `IAsyncEnumerable`, but the runtime type of an `IQueryable` may be an `IAsyncEnumerable`. This is implied by the [implementation of `AsAsyncEnumerable`](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/e2606903a208db8f2373c3dbf4bfeaf098639345/src/EFCore/Extensions/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs#L3245).

ASP.NET Core does not treat `IAsyncEnumerable` or `IQueryable` specially. It defers to `System.Text.Json` to serialize an object based on its runtime type. We can see how that works by [searching the source](https://github.com/search?q=IAsyncEnumerable+repo%3Adotnet%2Fruntime+path%3A%2Fsrc%2Flibraries%2FSystem.Text.Json%2F&type=Code&ref=advsearch&l=&l=).

And `System.Text.Json` does not treat `IQueryable` specially. If it happens to be an `IAsyncEnumerable`, it will be treated as such. Otherwise, it will be enumerated synchronously as an `IEnumerable`. So if you want this default behavior, a controller action can simply return an `IQueryable` (or `Task<IQueryable>`, etc.)

The only reason to modify the return type is if you know the `IQueryable` is an `IAsyncEnumerable`, and you want to avoid the [potential complications of streaming](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/32483#issuecomment-849348895). In that case, call [`ToListAsync`](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/e2606903a208db8f2373c3dbf4bfeaf098639345/src/EFCore/Extensions/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs#L2327) to materialize the result in the controller.

Comment: this is a good answer, but then I read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/async And I got a little more confused as to whether async (in EF) should be used at all. They have a warning of some bugs (which I think the OP was referring to). I noticed in my own code my paginatedList class is using ToListAsync(), and I'm wondering if ToList() would actually be faster.

Comment: @pcalkins I think my original answer was a bit wrong. Edited.